# i need an image to slide left and show another image underneath then slide back into place after a few seconds

Tags: jquery, html, image, slide

I am trying to click on an image and have it slide away showing another image underneath. after a few second delay I need the first image to slide back over the other image. I'm not sure my html has correct id's.

CSS

```
.dr {
align-content: center;
}

.container {
width: 960px;
margin: 20px auto;
}

.contentl {
float: left;
width: 480px;
margin: 10px;
padding: 10px;
}

.contentr {
float: left;
width: 480px;
margin: 10px;
padding: 10px;
}
```

(JS for one requirement that works, however I need the second image not to show until the first image is clicked on. )

```
 <script> 
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('img').load(function() {
        $(this).data('height', this.height);
    }).bind('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {
        $(this).stop().animate({
            height: $(this).data('height') * (e.type === 'mouseenter' ? 1.5 
: 1)
        });
    });


});
</script>


<body>

<h1>Guessing Game</h1>

<div id="container">

<div id="contentl">
<p id="dr" align="center">
<img id="i1"
```

src="file:///C:/Users/billi/Google%20Drive/School/INMD215/assignments/week%206/Media/gg%20media/door1.jpg" alt="Door One"/>

```
<div id="contentr">
<p id="dr" align="center">
<img id="i1" src="file:///C:/Users/billi/Google%20Drive/School/INMD215/assignments/week%206/Media/gg%20media/door2.jpg" alt="Door Two"/>
<img id="i2" src="file:///C:/Users/billi/Google%20Drive/School/INMD215/assignments/week%206/Media/gg%20media/pog.png" alt="pot of gold"/>
    </p>
    </div>

</div>

</body>
```

Comment: You said you want to click the image but you're using `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events

Comment: the function it shows it also a requirement so that one worked. I added your code and now all three requirements work! you rock!

Comment: ok, i misread the requirement. sooo.. the bottom_image needs to fade into view only after the top image has slid to the side?

Comment: No sweat. Coming right up!

Comment: @shammel lee this is fabulous but the second photo fades out instead of in. I tried playing with it and looking it up but I'm coming up short.

Comment: Did you run my example?

Comment: yes. mine is just there. your's fades in quickly..  my code  $(function(){
   $('.top_image').click(function(event){
    var $top_image = $(this);
    var $bottom_image = $('.bottom_image');
    
    $top_image.animate({
     left: '-300px'
    }, function() {
     window.setTimeout(function(){
      $top_image.animate({left: '0px'});
         $bottom_image.animate({opacity: 0});
     }, 2500);
    });
    
    $bottom_image.animate({opacity: 1});
    });
   });

Comment: I just ran that code. The only difference from my example is the top image moves left 300px vs my 150px. Also, the bottom image only fades out when the top image moves back to its original position. Is this not what you want?

Comment: no, i wanted it to fade in when the top image slid to the side.

Comment: and never fade out?

Comment: correct, that is not listed in the requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Run this bad boy…

```js
$(function(){
  $('.top_image').click(function(event){
    var $top_image = $(this);
    var $bottom_image = $('.bottom_image');

    $top_image.animate({
      left: '-150px'
    },function(){
      window.setTimeout(function(){
        $top_image.animate({left: '0px'});
      },2500); // wait 2.5 seconds before sliding back
    });

    $bottom_image.animate({opacity: 1}, 1000);
});
});
```

```css
.image_container{position:relative; width:150px; height:100px;margin:auto}
img{display:block; position:absolute}
.top_image{cursor:pointer}
.bottom_image{opacity:0}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
<div class='image_container'>
  <img class='bottom_image' src='http://68.media.tumblr.com/a203e3d842f73161fbf13318a08d69ad/tumblr_nrxh7u6nwX1ts2l6wo1_250.jpg' width='150'/>
  <img class='top_image' src='https://www.pets4homes.co.uk/images/classifieds/2016/09/26/1403628/large/smooth-haired-miniature-dapple-dachshund-57ea690ac071a.jpg' width='150' />
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```